# Struggling with arrays and scaning things into them

Tags: c

I am working on my homework for my computer science class and this code is part of a large chunk that is not yet written, my question is on the syntax for my arrays and reading floats into them. We have not gone over this yet but I knew this should be possible based on other programming languages that I have learned. Also on the second if statement would that syntax be right or would it be something else like if (answer == "Y" || "y").

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    float test_scores[100], ts;
    char answer;
    bool repeat = true;
    
    while (repeat)
    {
        printf("Enter in a test score:\n");
        if (ts>=0 && ts<=110)
        {
            scanf("%f", &test_scores[ts]);
            printf("You have entered in: %.2f\n", test_scores[ts]);
        }
        printf("Would you like to add another test score: Y/N\n");
        if ((answer = "Y" || "y"))
        {
            scanf("%c", &answer);
            printf("You have chosen to enter in another score.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            repeat = false;
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check your logic here: `if ((answer = "Y" || "y"))`. It means `if ((answer = ("Y" || "y")))` and that's probably not what you intended.

Comment: Side note: This is a place where I'll often use `tolower` so that case won't matter.

Comment: @user4581301 it is C not C++

Comment: If you use a debugger, you can answer this yourself :)

Comment: @0___________ took me a moment to catch what you meant there. I <expletive deleted>ed that up two ways.

Comment: `ts` has no defined value by the time the program reaches `ts>=0`, so Crom only knows what will happen. Program won't likely visibly fail at that point, but you can't know what it will do. `test_scores[ts]`, on the other hand, could blow up violently. If it'll compile at all. Array indexes should be performed with integers, not floating point numbers. You can't get the item at `array[3.1459]`.

Comment: You need to better define in your head and in the code, exactly what `ts` is intended to represent. In `if (ts>=0 && ts<=110)` it is being used as a score. At `scanf("%f", &test_scores[ts]);` it is being used as an index into the array of test scores. It can't be both.

Comment: General order of operations: Get value from user. Test to make sure you got a value from the user. If not, ask again. Otherwise test that the value you got from the user is in a valid range. If not, ask again. Otherwise use the value. Try to do any of these steps out of order and the program will not work. Leave out any of these steps and hackers will have a fun time breaking your program.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%c", &answer);
        if ((answer = "Y" || "y"))
```

two lines - plenty problems.

1. ALways check the result of the `scanf`
2. `answer = "Y" || "y"` assigns the result of the logical expression which checks if the pointer to string literal "Y" is not NULL, which is `1`. As `a || b` id `a` is `true` evaluates to `true` the second part is not eveluted. So the answer will be assigned with the integer `1`. if ((answer = "Y" || "y")) is always true.
3. `answer` is char. "Y" and "y" are strings and those cannot be compared (at least let us make this simplifying assumption)

it has to be:

```
if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y')
```

4. `test_scores[ts]`: `ts` is `float` but only integers can be used as array subscripts.

I did not analyze the logic of the program.

Generally, I would suggest a good C book as you need to learn the basic topics.